# Reading const parameter from .dat/.txt file

Tags: c++

I was looking over any relevant topics related to the subject. Having a really hard time comprehending them. Here is a code snippet that I am working on

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    plbInit(&argc, &argv);

    global::directories().setOutputDir("./1/");

    const T Ra = 5.15782958531050;
    const T lx  = 1.0;
    const T ly  = 1.0;
    const T uMax  = 1e-3;
    const T Pr = 0.00354054054054;

    const T hotTemperature = 1.0;
    const T coldTemperature = 0.0;
    const plint resolution = 999;

        RayleighBenardFlowParam<T,NSDESCRIPTOR,ADESCRIPTOR> parameters (
         Ra,
         Pr,
         uMax,
         coldTemperature,
         hotTemperature,
         resolution,
         lx,
         ly

   );
}
```

What I would really like to do is to take all the const parameters as input from a .dat/txt file.
By definition I would need to initialize them at the same time. Can't really find a convenient way to do that using ifstream.

Comment: If you are trying to use data read from a file to set const variables you cannot do that.  If you want to read in all of the values with one read you could wrap them all in a struct and then read the file in binary mode into the struct.

Comment: Have a set of non-const parameters, pass that to a function setting configuration values and make that set constant: const Parameters& initialize(Parameters&)

Comment: What's `T` actually (look all like `double` or `float`)? Do you vae some confusions about how to use template classes? And how is the `RayleighBenardFlowParam()` template class actually declared (that's nothing standard)?

Comment: Use a function `T load(std::istream&);` and then write `const T value = load(in);` where `in` is your `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "c++ read from text file".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If you have _mjolnir_ at hand, and don't want to dupe immediately, provide the title along with the link though please. /OT Nice to meet another peer BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really poviding enough context for that mysterious `RayleighBenardFlowParam` template class you're mentioning in your sample (please always consider to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking about code).
And also something like

> ```
> const T Ra = 5.15782958531050;
>    // ^
> ```

doesn't really make sense. `T` is only valid in context of the template class you're referring to, and you'll need to give it a concrete type for instantiations of that class.
I can guess the declaration of the `RayleighBenardFlowParam` class (and of it's constructor) looks somehow like

```
 template<typename T, typename NsDescriptor, typename ADescriptor>
 class RayleighBenardFlowParam {
 public:
     RayleighBenardFlowParam
        ( const T& Ra
        , const T& Pr
        , const T& uMax
        , const T& coldTemperature
        , const T& hotTemperature
        , const plint& resolution
        , const T& lx
        , const T& ly);
 };
```

But by means of how to read values from a *`.dat/.txt`* file and provide parameters to functions, that want to see `const` values, this can be easily answered:

> What I would really like to do is to take all the `const` parameters as input from a .dat/txt file.
>   By definition I would need to initialize them at the same time.

**Note:** You don't need the variable types to be declared `const` providing them as `const` references for parameters anywhere. That can be deduced by the compiler automatically.

You simply don't have any `const` variable declarations for these values

```
double Ra;
double lx;
double ly;
double uMax;
double Pr;

double hotTemperature;
double coldTemperature;
plint resolution;

std::isfstream input("MyFile.dat")
input >> Ra;
input >> lx;
input >> ly;
input >> uMax;
input >> Pr;

input >> hotTemperature;
input >> coldTemperature;
input >> resolution;

if(input) {
    RayleighBenardFlowParam<double,NSDESCRIPTOR,ADESCRIPTOR> parameters (
       Ra,
       Pr,
       uMax,
       coldTemperature,
       hotTemperature,
       resolution,
       lx,
       ly);
 }
```

Where the content of `MyFile.dat` looks as follows

```
5.15782958531050
1.0
1.0
1e-3
0.00354054054054
1.0
0.0
999
```

Comment: Thanks, alot...yes I did figured that the compiler has figured that itself. Another way that I found declaring them const is ti use a non const dummy variable for reading from the dat file and initializing the const with that variable